# Can we build decision trees faster if we use an approximate local maximum search method to find split points?

Tags: random-forest, cart, boosting

In CART and similar algorithms, when we want to create a split, we iterate over all possible split values, evaluate the score (Gini, information gain) produced by the split. Then we pick the split with the highest/lowest score.

A student of mine proposed: why don't we use something like [Ternary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search) to find an approximately best split? For a large dataset, when building an ensemble of trees, considering fewer split points could make a large difference in speed.

We plotted the possible split points vs infogain fora small dataset and found it to be like this:
[image: Possible splits vs infogain]

There is Extra Trees where the basic idea is that instead of iterating over each possible split, we pick some split points at random and use the best one among them.

Could we use an optimization technique to find the best split point in less time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can approximate split points and potentially save some time. Some implementations already do it one way or another. As you found already, ExtraTrees chooses split points randomly saving a lot of time (at least on this part), xgboost uses 10 quantiles and evaluates splits at those points only.

If you were to change this, you should keep in mind that the graph of the score/Gini/importance won't necessarily look as nice as it does in your image, but it could have any shape, so your proposed method should be somewhat robust.